# What is the purpose of the -U option in Zsh's autoload

Tags: zsh

The man page for zsh mentions for the `autoload` command an option `-U`, but doesn't explain it. However, it refers for unexplain options to the `functions` command. Looking up `functions` in the man page, I see that it indeed accepts `-U`, but it isn't explained either.

In examples on the Net, I sometimes see `autoload` used with and sometimes without `-U`. What is this option doing, and where is it explained? The explanation must be somewhere in the zsh man pages, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214296/what-is-the-difference-between-autoload-and-autoload-u-in-zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autoload` is equivalent to `functions -u`, and  `functions` is in turn equivalent to `typeset -f`.

If you look up the section on `typeset` in the `zshbuiltins(1)` man page, you’ll finally find your answer:

> The `-u` and `-U` flags cause the  function  to  be marked for autoloading; `-U` also causes alias expansion to be suppressed when  the  function  is  loaded.